# Spacing items on a row in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I can move the "indicator" anywhere I want, but the "Button" and "DiagValue" I ONLY seem to be able move to different rows... I need to move to different columns or different "x".

[image]

```
Row{
          spacing: table.rowSpacing

          Button {
              width: 60
              //x: 100   //this does NOTHING!
              //y: 159  
              text: tr_NOOP("Help")

              onClicked: {
                  app.dialogs.message.title = trans("Water Status")
                  app.dialogs.message.body = trans("Rate is not met.")
                  app.dialogs.message.show();
              }
          }

          Indicator {
              x: -50
              //y: 159
              ok: false
          }

          DiagValue {
              MeasuredValue {
                  id: lowFlowValueText
                  rawValueUnit: "gpm"
                  unit: "gpm"
                  precision: 1
              }
              label: trans("Water Flow Setting")
              value: lowFlowValueText.text
          }
    }
```

Comment: What is table.rowSpacing? Is it correclty defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you set proper spacing in Row and align it horizontally, it should look like what you need.

```
Row {
    spacing: table.rowSpacing
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    ...
}
```

And you don't need to supply x value when your elements are inside `Row`, `Row` element will decide x value based on spacing and width of individual child.

Answer (score 0):

A `Row` will define the horizontal location and the horizontal extent (size) of the elements that it contains. It doesn't make sense to manually try to override either `x` or `width` for elements in a row, in fact it will generate warnings.

You can, of course, override the vertical position within a `Row`.

Your elements must be supplying sensible default sizes and must react sensibly to being resized, so without seeing how you define the components (Button, Indicator, DiagValue), it'd be impossible to say exactly where the problem is. For stock controls, it works fine.

Comment: modifying `width` does not pose any problem. `Row` doesn't modify it. `RowLayout` does.